# How to get Filters on custom products listing?

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, layered-navigation

I have created a cms page on which i am showing all the products which are on sale now i need filters on the same page but it filters are not coming here.

I have tried placing the filter block in Layout Update XML of CMS Page but it didn't work.

Hope anyone knows the solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the following code as a layout update:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```